# Почему возникает ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: *** is not a function

Tags: javascript, функции

Периодически, при разработке на `JavaScript` возникает ошибка: **Uncaught TypeError: *** is not a function**

Например в этом коде:

```
const result = this.response;
result.forEach((e) => console.log(e));
```

> **Uncaught TypeError: result.forEach is not a function**

Или в этом:

```
const errors = response.errors.map(item => item.toString());
```

> **Uncaught TypeError: response.errors.map is not a function**

Как понять, что это за ошибка, что оно означает, почему появляется и как её исправить?

Comment: не надо было смешивать две ошибки

Comment: @Grundy Ошибку [cannot read property of undefined or null](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o) перенес в отдельный пост

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Рассматривать будем на примере данного объекта

```
const data = {
    name: 'TypeError',
    message: '',
    errors: null,
    sayHi: function() {
        console.log(this.name)
    }
}
```

### Uncaught TypeError: *** is not a function

Данная ошибка возникает в том случае, когда у объекта мы пытаемся вызвать метод(функцию), но она таковой не является.

```
data.getName(); // <- Uncaught TypeError: data.getName is not a function
data.errors(); // <- Uncaught TypeError: data.errors is not a function
```

В первом случае `getName()` нет в объекте, во втором, `errors` не является функцией.

#### Несоответствие типов

Возможно, мы ожидаем, что к нам придет массив и мы пытаемся выполнить:

```
data.name.forEach(item => console.log(item));
```

Получим ошибку, так как у строк нет метода `forEach`

#### Ошибка экспорта/импорта зависимостей

```
// Экспорт из файла
const fnc = (a) => { return a*a; }
export { func: fnc() }
// Импорт
import { func } from 'module';
func(); // <- func is not a function
```

Мы ожидали, что будет импортирована функция, однако вместо самой функции, мы импортировали результат ее выполнения. Функции должны экспортироваться без вызова **()**

##### Как избежать подобных ошибок?

Проверять, что приходит в объекте и существуют ли в объекте нужные нам данные. Один из вариантов проверки, воспользоваться `console.log()`.
Можно начать с последнего ключа, однако лучше вывести весь пусть, чтобы понимать структуру, с которой работаем:

```
console.log(data) // { name: 'TypeError', message: '', errors: null, sayHi: [Function] }
console.log(data.errors) // null
console.log(data.sayHi) // [Function: sayHi]
```

Перед вызовом функции, желательно проверить ключ на тип. И если наш ключ является функцией, то вызывать.

```
// data существует, есть ключ sayHi и sayHi функция
if (data && data.sayHi && typeof data.sayHi === 'function') {
    data.sayHi();
}
```

При проверке в `if` лучше указывать полную цепочку ключей для проверки, так как, например, следующая конструкция вызовет исключение, т.к. `data.values` не существует:

```
if (data.values.showValue && typeof data.values.showValue === 'function') {
    console.log(data.values.showValue());
}
```

Сократить код можно, воспользовавшись оператором необязательной цепочки вызовов '**?.**':

```
// data существует?, есть ключ sayHi и sayHi функция
if (data?.sayHi && typeof data.sayHi === 'function') {
    data.sayHi();
}
```

Оператор **необязательной цепочки вызовов** будет проверять значение слева. Если значение `null` или `undefined`, цепочка прерывается и возвращается значение **`undefined`**.

Порой, такие ошибки, даже когда мы уверены в правильности данных, могут быть вызваны банальной опечаткой. Проверяйте себя и свой код!

```
if (data && data.sayHi && typeof data.sayHi === 'function') {
    data.sayHI(); // sayHI нет, но есть sayHi
}
```

#### Импорт/экспорт функций

При экспорте функций, передается только имя функции.

```
// Экспорт из файла
const fnc = (a) => { return a*a; }
export { func: fnc } // Нет ()
// Импорт
import { func } from 'module';
func(2); // <- 4
```

Отдельное исключение есть для функций или классов, когда нам это необходимо. Допустим нам нужен глобальный счетчик.

```
function counterFnc() {
  let count = 0;
  return () => {
    return ++count;
  }
}

class Counter {
  #count = 0;
  inc() {
    return ++this.#count;
  }
}
const incer = new Counter();
export { 
  counter: counterFnc(),
  countCl: incer,
  increase: incer.inc
}
// import
import { counter, countCl, increase } from 'module';
counter(); // OK
countCl.inc(); // OK
increase(); // OK
```