# Как перебрать свойства объектов в массиве

Tags: javascript

Задача: Мне нужно перебрать `student` и `runLab` которые находятся в объектах, а объекты находятся в массиве `arrayOfObjects`.

Проблема: Код выдает ошибку

```
mainScript.js:37 Uncaught TypeError: elementMethod.runLab is not a function
    at mainScript.js:37:41
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at gradeLabs (mainScript.js:35:11)
    at mainScript.js:43:1
```

Пытался решить никак не могу. Подскажите как исправить ошибку чтобы код работал нормально.

```js
const arrayOfObjects = [
    {
        student: 'Dmitriy',
        runLab () {
            return 1;
        }
    },
    {
        student: 'Andrew',
        runLab () {
            return 2;
        }
    },
    {
        student: 'Mellisa',
        runLab () {
            return 3;
        }
    },
    {
        student: 'Ann',
        runLab () {
            return 4;
        }
    },
];
function gradeLabs(array,expectedResult) {
    array.forEach((elementName,elementFunc) => {
        const resultName = elementName.student;
        const resultLab = elementFunc.runLab();
        if (resultLab === expectedResult) {
            console.log('Student has PASSED the test',resultName);
        }
    });
}
gradeLabs(arrayOfObjects,1);
```

Comment: Подробнее про ошибку [Uncaught TypeError: elementMethod.runLab is not a function](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479423/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-is-not-a-function) можете почитать. Там же приведен пример, как искать ошибки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все что вам надо сделать, это заменить elementFunc на elementName. Т.к. вы пытались вызвать метод **.runLab** у числа(индекс текущего элемента):

```
const resultLab = elementName.runLab();
```

Потому что у метода массива forEach 3 параметра - текущий элемент, индекс массива и сам массив

> .forEach(function (item, index, array) {})

Полный код:

```js
const arrayOfObjects = [
  {
    student: 'Dmitriy',
    runLab () {
      return 1;
    }
  },
  {
    student: 'Andrew',
    runLab () {
      return 2;
    }
  },
  {
    student: 'Mellisa',
    runLab () {
      return 3;
    }
  },
  {
    student: 'Ann',
    runLab () {
      return 4;
    }
  },
];
function gradeLabs(array,expectedResult) {
  array.forEach((elementName) => {
    if (elementName.runLab() === expectedResult) {
      console.log('Student has PASSED the test', elementName.student);
    }
  });
}
gradeLabs(arrayOfObjects,2);
```

Хотя я бы рекомендовал вам для поиска 1 элемента массива воспользоваться методом **.find** или циклом **for**(т.к. при нахождении желаемого элемента, дальнейший перебор можно прервать).