# Почему не хочет запускаться тест Jest?

Tags: javascript, jest

```js
const getAge = require('./mainScripts');
const { test } = require('picomatch');
const { expect } = require('@jest/globals');


test (
    'Проверяем функцию getAge на тип данных',
    () => {
        expect(getAge(typeof (`${this.firstName}'s old is ${this.age} years`)).toBe('string'));
    }
)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код:

```js
class Student {
    constructor(firstName,lastName,yearOfBirth,arrayOfGrades) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
        this.arrayOfGrades = arrayOfGrades;
        this.age = new Date().getFullYear() - this.yearOfBirth;
        this.avgMark = arrayOfGrades.reduce((sum,item) => {
            return sum += item
        }, 0) / arrayOfGrades.length;

    }
    //______Возраст студента______//
    getAge () {
        return (`${this.firstName}'s old is ${this.age} years`);
    }
    //______Средний бал______//
    averageMark () {
        return(`${this.firstName}'s average mark is ${this.avgMark}`);
    }
}

class Visit extends Student {
    constructor(firstName, lastName, yearOfBirth, arrayOfGrades) {
        super(firstName, lastName, yearOfBirth, arrayOfGrades);
        this.visitinMagazine = [];
    }
    //______Используется когда студент был на занятие______//
    present () {
        if (this.visitinMagazine.length < 26) {
            this.visitinMagazine.push(true);
            return this;
        } else {
            return this.visitinMagazine.pop();
        }
    }
    //______Используется когда студент НЕ был на занятие______//
    absent () {
        if (this.visitinMagazine.length < 26) {
            this.visitinMagazine.push(false);
            return this;
        } else {
            return this.visitinMagazine.pop();
        }
    }
}

 class Calculation extends Visit {
    constructor(firstName, lastName, yearsOfBirth, arrayOfGrades) {
        super(firstName, lastName, yearsOfBirth, arrayOfGrades);
    }

     //______Проверяем среднюю оценку и посейщение______//
     summary () {
         const averageVisit = this.visitinMagazine.filter((element) => element === true).length / this.visitinMagazine.length;
         if (this.avgMark > 90 && averageVisit > 0.9) {
             return console.log('Cool!');
         } else if (this.avgMark > 90 || averageVisit > 0.9) {
             return console.log('Good, but it can be better!');
         } else {
             return console.log('Radish');
         }
     }
 }
//______Экземпляры расчетов______//
const calculate = new Calculation('Dmitriy', 'Yaroshchuk', 2001, [70, 80, 90, 100, 90, 90, 99, 100, 95, 100]);
const calculate1 = new Calculation('Andrew', 'Kavetsky', 2000, [90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 100, 100, 95, 93]);
const calculate2 = new Calculation('Diana', 'Koko', 1999, [70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 75, 75, 75, 93]);

console.log(calculate.getAge());
console.log(calculate1.getAge());
console.log(calculate2.getAge());

console.log(calculate.averageMark());
console.log(calculate1.averageMark());
console.log(calculate2.averageMark());


//______Посейщение уроков______//
calculate.present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().absent().absent();

//______Посейщение уроков______//
calculate1.absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().present().present();

//______Посейщение уроков______//
calculate2.present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent();


calculate.summary();
calculate1.summary();
calculate2.summary();

module.exports = this.getAge;
// module.exports = this.averageMark();
// module.exports = this.present();
// module.exports = this.absent();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему возникает ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: \*\*\* is not a function](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479423/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-is-not-a-function)

Comment: @SwaD мне вроде не выдает ошибку Uncaught TypeError: *** is not a function

Comment: Второй скрин говорит об обратном ) Экспорт функции делается без скобок, иначе в экспорт попадает результат ее работы. Вместо `this.getAge()` надо `this.getAge`. Ну и надо убедиться, что у вас в this getAge существует

Comment: @SwaD подскажите устранил предыдущею ошибку появилась новая TypeError: regex.exec is not a function (Прикрепил скрин). Почитал в интернете пишут что нужно использовать регулярное выражение не очень понимаю как это реализовать

Comment: Кто такой picomatch? Если уберете этот импорт, тест должен запуститься. Как я понимаю, фукнция test Jesta перетерласть функцией test из пакета picomatch

Comment: @SwaD данная строка `const { test } = require('picomatch');` написалась автоматически когда я писал тест. Сейчас попробую ее убрать

Comment: @SwaD Запустил тест выдало следующую ошибку  TypeError: getAge is not a function, фото прикрепил к заданию. Не могу понять из-за чего она появляется, вроде сделал все как вы посоветовали и как написано в документации .

Comment: Приложите к вопросу ваш код из mainScripts.js, Подозреваю, что вы намудрили с импортом/экспортом. Код текстом

Comment: @SwaD добавил код

Comment: Так у вас нет фукнции getAge. this скорее всего пуст(undefined). getAge принадлежит классу Student. Т.е. вы экспортируете undefined, вот и получаете ошибку. Экспортируйте метод из экзепляра класса либо сам экземпляр или может даже класс. Создайте экземляр в тестовом файле и дергайте методы для теста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле с классами добавьте перед классом Calculation export

```
export class Calculation extends Visit {
```

А дальше создавайте тест

```
const { Calculation } = require('./mainScripts');

describe('Тестируем класс Calculation', () => {
  const name = 'Dmitriy';
  const age = 2001;
  const lastName = 'Yaroshchuk';
  const calc = new Calculation(name, lastName, age, [70, 80, 90, 100, 90, 90, 99, 100, 95, 100]);
  test('Проверка на типы', () => {
    expect(calc.getAge()).toBeTruthy()
    expect(typeof calc.getAge()).toBe('string')
  })

  test('Выводит имя и год рождения', () => {
    expect(calc.getAge()).toBe(`${name}'s old is ${2023 - age} years`)
  })

})
```

Если хотите протестировать именно экземпляр класса, то экспортируете его при создании

```
export const calculate = new Calculation(...)
```

Импортируете и пишите тест

```
const { calculate } = require('./mainScripts');

describe('Тестируем экземпляр класса', () => {
  test('Проверка на типы', () => {
    expect(calculate.getAge()).toBeTruthy()
    expect(typeof calculate.getAge()).toBe('string')
  })

  test('Выводит имя и год рождения', () => {
    expect(calculate.getAge()).toBe(`Dmitriy's old is 22 years`)
  })
})
```

Comment: подскажите опять столкнулся с ошибкой `SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'`
сделал все как вы сказали. Прикрепил  2 фото к вопросу

Comment: @NANO_996 Попробуйте убрать все export и в конце файла написать `module.exports = { Calculation: Calculation, calculate: calculate }`

Comment: Заработало. Могли бы вы объяснить что данная строка значит `module.exports = { Calculation: Calculation, calculate: calculate }`

Comment: @NANO_996 Это экспорт переменных. Он необходим для require. Это более старая версия испортов/экспортов. Если вкратце, то это переход с commonJS на ES6 стандарт. Более подробнее можно почитать [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46677752/the-difference-between-requirex-and-import-x) - Что бы не дублировать

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста тестирую функцию `summary` в тесте выдает `undefined` хотя в консоль в браузере выводит `Cool !` Прикрепил скрин.

Comment: Посмотрите на метод внимательно и ответьте самому себе - что **возвращает** данная фукнция?

Comment: я правильно понял так как у метода `summary` нет return она возвращает `undefined` ?

Comment: т.к. она ничего не возвращает, вот и undefined

Comment: скажите можно ли ее изменить чтобы она возвращала `Cool!` ,  ` Good, but it can be better!` ,
`Radish` ? Я просто не очень понимаю как в `return` передать условия при которых будет выводиться конкретный текст.

Comment: @NANO_996 Можно. Мы тут и так знатно нафлудили. Создайте вопрос с чем возникли сложности и вам помогут

Comment: скажите данная строка `module.exports = { Calculation: Calculation, calculate: calculate }` которую вы посоветовали написать выдает в консоль `Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined`, можно ли как-то данную ошибку устранить ?

Comment: То же самое, что и выше... Оформите в виде вопроса, куда приложите код, который у вас получился и ошибку, которую получаете. Изменений в вашем коде уже много. Тем более, что до этого все работало