# Как корректно реализовать вызов ошибки с помощью try catch в функции?

Tags: javascript

В методах `present` и `absent` если длина массива `this.visitinMagazine > 25` должно выбрасывать ошибку и удалять последний элемент массива, но этого не происходит. Подскажите как реализовать.

Методы `present` и `absent`:

```js
class Visit extends Student {
    constructor(firstName, lastName, yearOfBirth, arrayOfGrades) {
        super(firstName, lastName, yearOfBirth, arrayOfGrades);
        this.visitinMagazine = [];
    }
    //______Используется когда студент был на занятие______//
    present () {
        try {
            if (this.visitinMagazine.length > 25) {
                throw new Error(`Обучение Happy End`)
                return this.visitinMagazine.pop();
            } else {
                this.visitinMagazine.push(true);
                return this;
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Проверьте посещение ${this.firstName} ${error}`)
        }

    }
    //______Используется когда студент НЕ был на занятие______//
    absent () {
        try {
            if (this.visitinMagazine.length > 25) {
                throw new Error(`Обучение Happy End`)
                return this.visitinMagazine.pop();
            } else {
                this.visitinMagazine.push(false);
                return this;
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Проверьте посещение ${this.firstName} ${error}`)
        }
    }
}
```

Общий код:

```js
class Student {
    constructor(firstName,lastName,yearOfBirth,arrayOfGrades) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
        this.arrayOfGrades = arrayOfGrades;
        this.age = new Date().getFullYear() - this.yearOfBirth;
        this.avgMark = arrayOfGrades.reduce((sum,item) => {
            return sum += item
        }, 0) / arrayOfGrades.length;

    }
    //______Возраст студента______//
    getAge () {
        const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
        try {
            if (this.yearOfBirth < 1900 || this.yearOfBirth >= currentYear) {
                throw new Error('Год рождения студента указан неверно')
            } else {
                return (`${this.firstName}'s old is ${this.age} years`);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Исправьте год рождения ${this.firstName} ${error}`)
        }
    }
    //______Средний бал______//
    averageMark () {
        try {
            if (this.avgMark > 100 || this.avgMark < 0) {
                throw new Error('Оценка расчитана неверно')
            } else {
                return(`${this.firstName}'s average mark is ${this.avgMark}`);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(`Проверьте правильность ввода данных ${this.firstName} ${error}`)
        }
    }
}

class Visit extends Student {
    constructor(firstName, lastName, yearOfBirth, arrayOfGrades) {
        super(firstName, lastName, yearOfBirth, arrayOfGrades);
        this.visitinMagazine = [];
    }
    //______Используется когда студент был на занятие______//
    present () {
        try {
            if (this.visitinMagazine.length > 25) {
                throw new Error(`Обучение Happy End`)
                return this.visitinMagazine.pop();
            } else {
                this.visitinMagazine.push(true);
                return this;
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Проверьте ппосещение ${this.firstName} ${error}`)
        }

    }
    //______Используется когда студент НЕ был на занятие______//
    absent () {
        try {
            if (this.visitinMagazine.length > 25) {
                throw new Error(`Обучение Happy End`)
                return this.visitinMagazine.pop();
            } else {
                this.visitinMagazine.push(false);
                return this;
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Проверьте посещение ${this.firstName} ${error}`)
        }
    }
}

 class Calculation extends Visit {
    constructor(firstName, lastName, yearsOfBirth, arrayOfGrades) {
        super(firstName, lastName, yearsOfBirth, arrayOfGrades);
    }

     //______Проверяем среднюю оценку и посейщение______//
     summary () {
         const averageVisit = this.visitinMagazine.filter((element) => element === true).length / this.visitinMagazine.length;
         if (this.avgMark > 90 && averageVisit > 0.9) {
             return 'Cool!';
         } else if (this.avgMark > 90 || averageVisit > 0.9) {
            return 'Good, but it can be better!';
         } else {
             return 'Radish';
         }
     }
 }
//______Экземпляры расчетов______//
const calculate = new Calculation('Dmitriy', 'Yaroshchuk', 2001, [70, 80, 90, 100, 90, 90, 99, 100, 95, 100]);
const calculate1 = new Calculation('Andrew', 'Kavetsky', 2000, [90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 100, 100, 95, 93]);
const calculate2 = new Calculation('Diana', 'Koko', 1999, [70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 75, 75, 75, 93]);

console.log(calculate.getAge());
console.log(calculate1.getAge());
console.log(calculate2.getAge());

console.log(calculate.averageMark());
console.log(calculate1.averageMark());
console.log(calculate2.averageMark());


//______Посейщение уроков______//
calculate.present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().absent().absent().absent();

//______Посейщение уроков______//
calculate1.absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().present().present();

//______Посейщение уроков______//
calculate2.present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent();

console.log(calculate.visitinMagazine);
console.log(calculate1.visitinMagazine);
console.log(calculate2.visitinMagazine);

console.log(calculate.summary());
console.log(calculate1.summary());
console.log(calculate2.summary());


if (typeof module === 'object') {
    module.exports = { Calculation: Calculation, calculate: calculate }
}
```

Comment: У вас будет ошибка, если вы вернете эксепшн. Следующий .absent() сломается, т.к. не будет нужного метода. Какого поведения вы хотите добиться? Ну вот 26й элемент прилетел - что должно произойти?

Comment: @SwaD по заданию есть массив `this.visitinMagazine`, в нем 25 частей, поначалу он не заполнен, но на 25 частей. Это массив, в котором отмечается посещаемость, всякий раз, когда мы вызываем метод .present() на очередное пустое место, в массив записывается true, когда вызываем .absent() - записывается false. После выполнения данной части задания в метод надо добавить `try catch` в котором если длина массива `this.visitinMagazine > 25` должно выбрасывать ошибку и удалять последний элемент массива

Comment: Возможно не правильно реализованы сами методы и их вызовы? Что по первому исходному заданию должен возвращать метод?

Comment: @SwaD если мы вызываем метод `present` он добавляет в массив `this.visitinMagazine` `true`.
 Если мы вызываем метод `absent` он добавляет в массив `this.visitinMagazine` `false`.

Comment: Про то, что должен что то возвращать есть информация? Вы то возвращаете, условно, себя...

Comment: @SwaD про то что он должен возвращать информации нету

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. После throw другие инструкции не выполняются
2. Ты должен возвращать this

   ```
    present() {
      try {
        if (this.visitinMagazine.length > 25) {
          throw new Error("");
        } else {
          this.visitinMagazine.push(true);
          return this;
        }
      } catch (error) {
        this.visitinMagazine.pop();
        return this;
      }
    }
   ```

и absent()

```
absent() {
      try {
        if (this.visitinMagazine.length > 25) {
          throw new Error("");
        } else {
          this.visitinMagazine.push(false);
          return this;
        }
      } catch (error) {
        this.visitinMagazine.pop();
        return this;
      }
    }
```

Comment: вы потеряли строку `this.visitinMagazine.pop()` или она не нужна ?

Comment: я не знаю контекста задачи. если она нужна, то добавь перед строкой с return

Answer (score 1):

Вариант первый, не совсем по заданию, но правильный
Переделываем методы в такую конструкцию

```
absent () {
    if (this.visitinMagazine.length < 25) {
        this.visitinMagazine.push(false);
        return true;
    }
    this.visitinMagazine.pop();
    throw new Error(`Обучение для ${this.firstName} Happy End`)
}
```

Вызов методов делаем не цепочкой(что в целом было изначально не правильно), а в цикле, т.е. студент приходит каждый день, а не после (не)прихода предыдущего

```
for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    try {
        calculate1.absent();
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Студент протух: ', e)
        break;
    }
}
```

В цикле приходов ставим `try catch`, что бы отловить ошибку, т.к. мы ее там возможно ожидаем.

> Если по заданию реализовывать, то тут почти то же самое

```
absent() {
    try {
        if (this.visitinMagazine.length < 25) {
            this.visitinMagazine.push(false);
            return true;
        }
        throw new Error('Много пропусков')
    } catch (e) {
        this.visitinMagazine.pop();
        throw new Error(`Обучение для ${this.firstName} Happy End`)
    }
}
```

Внутри блока `try` генерим исключение, если количество посещений больше 25. Это исключение попадает в блок `catch`, из которого мы передаем ошибку туда, откуда вызван данный метод. Соответственно, ошибку надо там так же перехватывать.

Такая же логика должна действовать для метода **present()**

Comment: скажите если я реализовал метод так `absent() {
    try {
        if (this.visitinMagazine.length <= 25) {
            this.visitinMagazine.push(false);
            return true;
        }
        throw new Error('Много пропусков')
    } catch (e) {
        this.visitinMagazine.pop();
        throw new Error(`Обучение для ${this.firstName} Happy End`)
    }
}`
Почему при добавление 26 элемента в массив он не удаляется и не выкидывает ошибку а только когда добавляю 27 элемент выбрасывает ошибку ?

Comment: Ошибка в условии. `if (this.visitinMagazine.length <= 25)` заменить на `if (this.visitinMagazine.length < 25)`

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста написал таким образом метод `present () {
        try {
            if (this.visitinMagazine.length < 25) {
                this.visitinMagazine.push(true);
                return this;
            } else {
                throw new Error('Много посещений');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            this.visitinMagazine.pop();
            console.error(`${error} Обучение для ${this.firstName} Happy End`)
            return this
        }
    }`

Comment: И теперь если длина массива становится больше 25 то выбрасывает ошибку и удаляет последний элемент массива  и длина массива становится 24, а должна оставаться 25. Никак не могу понять как решить данную проблему.

Comment: @NANO_996 Ну судя по заданию так и должно быть. Тут выбора 2 либо добавлять 26, а потом отнимать 1, либо после 25 отнимать 1. Еще есть вариант не удалять 1, а просто не добавлять после 25, но это не сходится с вашим заданием. Я бы задал впорос тому, от кого это задание. А так, варинт с тем, что после 25 отнимается 1 и остается 24 мне кажется более правдивым

Answer (score 0):

> Инструкция throw позволяет генерировать исключения, определяемые
> пользователем. При этом выполнение текущей функции будет остановлено
> (инструкции после throw не будут выполнены), и управление будет
> передано в первый блок catch в стеке вызовов.

Поэтому return this.visitinMagazine.pop() не срабатывает. Перенеси этот return после throw в catch

```
present () {
    try {
        if (this.visitinMagazine.length > 25) {
            throw new Error(`Обучение Happy End`)
        } else {
            this.visitinMagazine.push(true);
            return this;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Проверьте посещение ${this.firstName} ${error}`);
        this.visitinMagazine.pop();
        return this;
    }
}
```

В функции absent тоже самое. Инструкции после throw не выполняются, поэтому перенеси в catch.

Comment: Если это сделать, то 27й вызов сломается...

Comment: возвращай `return this` вместо  `return this.visitinMagazine.pop();`

Comment: При цепочке вызовов, как у автора, после возврата ошибки, вы получите ошибку [calculate1.absent(...).absent is not a function](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479423/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-is-not-a-function) и дальнейшее исполнение скрипта прекратится

Comment: да, поправил. надо еще this возвращать