# Почему не работают примеры jquery.fancytree (tree.expandAll is not a function)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пытаюсь свернуть всё дерево по примеру и приведённому коду:
https://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/#sample-api.html

```
$.ui.fancytree.getTree("#tree").expandAll(false);
```

У себя пишу так:

```
var tree = $.ui.fancytree.getTree("#tree");

$("button#btnCollapseTree").click(function (e) {
    tree.expandAll(false);
});
```

Ошибка: **tree.expandAll is not a function**

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему возникает ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: \*\*\* is not a function](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479423/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-is-not-a-function)

Comment: Проверяйте, что у вас такое tree и есть ли там expandAll, а так же, чему он равен

Comment: `var tree = $("#tree").fancytree("getTree");` - может так?

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой код решает мою проблему (по клику закрыть все узлы, т.е. свернуть всё дерево):

```
$("#btnAllCollapse").click(function () {
    $("#tree")
        .fancytree("getRootNode")
        .visit(function (node) {
            node.setExpanded(false);
        });
    return false;
});
```