# Не получается отправить PUT запрос React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, redux

Добрый день и заранее спасибо.

Я пытаюсь вывести в консоль результат отправки Put запроса в React, но я не могу понять почему он не получает входные данные с input и данные с сервера о ошибке запроса.

Сервер на Node.js, база данных MongoDB

Вот функция получения с input значения, и в comment оно приходит

```
    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        dispatch(updateUserFinanceInfo({ comment }));
        clearInput();
    };
```

Вот компонент в React

```
 <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                            <label>
                                {commentDirty && commentError && (
                                    <span
                                        style={{
                                            color: "red",
                                            fontSize: 15,
                                            paddingTop: 4,
                                        }}
                                    >
                                        {errorSymbol}{" "}
                                    </span>
                                )}
                                <p>Comment</p>
                                <input
                                    onBlur={handleChange}
                                    onChange={commentHandler}
                                    type="text"
                                    value={comment}
                                    placeholder="Comment"
                                />
                            </label>
                            <button type="submit">
                                <span>Smenit</span>
                            </button>
                        </form>
```

Вот так я отправляю запрос:

```
export const updateUserFinanceInfo = createAsyncThunk(
    "auth/profile/update",
    async (_, { credentials, rejectWithValue }) => {
        console.log(credentials);
        try {
            console.log("credentials", credentials);
            const { data } = await axios.put(
                "auth/profile/update",
                credentials
            );
            console.log("data", data);
            return data;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return rejectWithValue(error);
        }
    }
);
```

Но в credentials ничего не приходит, а значит req.body пустой.

Я пытаюсь вывести результат res с сервера Node.js но получаю:

```
TypeError: res.status is not a function
    at Object.Update (helpers\statuses.js:65:20)
    at updateUserFinanceInfo (asmis-new-bd\controllers\auth\userControllers.js:146:28)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async asmis-new-bd\middlewares\ctrlWrapper.js:4:7
```

Вот так выгдлядит мой контроллер:

```
const updateUserFinanceInfo = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const data = await Repositories.findOneAndUpdate(
            req,
            req.user.workerId
        );

        if (!data) {
            return Helpers.Conflict(
                res,
                Helpers.HttpCode.CONFLICT,
                Helpers.Statuses.ERROR,
                Helpers.Messages.AGAIN
            );
        } else {
            return Helpers.Update(
                Helpers.HttpCode.OK,
                req,
                res,
                Helpers.Messages.UPDATED,
                Helpers.Statuses.SUCCESS
            );
        }
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
};
```

Вот так я отправляю на сервер данные:

```
const findOneAndUpdate = async (req, workerId) => {
    try {
        return await Auth.findOneAndUpdate(
            { workerId },
            { ...req.body },
            { new: true }
        );
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

Вот так я получаю res статусы - Успешный:

```
const Update = async (res, code, status, message, req) => {
    try {
        return res.status(code).json({
            code,
            status,
            message,
            data: {
                ...req.body,
            },
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

Отрицательный:

```
const Conflict = async (res, code, status, message) => {
    try {
        return res.status(code).json({
            code,
            status,
            message,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

Вот так выглядит моя схема:

```
const joiUpdateSchema = Joi.object({
    linkToPhoto: Joi.string(),
    username: Joi.string().min(5),
    name: Joi.string().min(3).max(15),
    surname: Joi.string().min(3).max(15),
    email: Joi.string().email().max(256),
    phoneNumber: Joi.string().min(9).max(13),
    language: Joi.string().valid(...lang),
    theme: Joi.string().valid(...theme),
    firm: Joi.string().min(2),
    workingContractType: Joi.string().valid(...workingCategory),
    comment: Joi.string(),
    additionalColumn: { workerInfo: Joi.string() },
});
```

Вот так я отправляю на сервер запрос:

```
router.put(
    "/profile/update",
    auth,
    validation(Schema.joiUpdateSchema, "Try it again"),
    ctrlWrapper(ctrl.updateUserFinanceInfo)
);
```

Вот так выглядит app.js на сервере

```
const authRouter = require("./routes/api/auth");

const app = express();

const formatsLogger = app.get("env") === "development" ? "dev" : "short";

app.use(logger(formatsLogger));
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.use("/api/auth", authRouter);

app.use((req, res) => {
    res.status(HttpCode.NOT_FOUND).json({
        code: HttpCode.NOT_FOUND,
        message: "Not found",
    });
    res.status(HttpCode.BAD_REQUEST).json({
        code: HttpCode.BAD_REQUEST,
        message: "Bad request",
    });
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    const {
        status = HttpCode.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
        message = "Server error",
    } = err;
    res.status(status).json({ message });
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему возникает ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: \*\*\* is not a function](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479423/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-is-not-a-function)

Comment: Смотрите внимательно на функцию **Update**. Как вы ее определили и как вызываете.

Comment: @SwaD Спасибо, я передавал функции параметры в неправильном порядке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была в получении res status на сервере

```
const Update = async (res, code, status, message, req) => {
    try {
        return res.status(code).json({
            code,
            status,
            message,
            data: {
                ...req.body,
            },
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```