# Не работает запуск/стоп HTML5 видео через jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

Есть HTML5-видео:

```
<video class="video js-video" controls>
    <source src="./video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Пытаюсь сделать запуск/паузу видео через jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var video = $(".js-video");

    function togglePlay() {
        if (video.paused || video.ended) {
            video.play();
        } else {
            video.pause();
        }
    }

    $(".js-play").click(function(){
        togglePlay();
    });

});
```

Но запуск/стоп не работают. В консоли появляются ошибки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему возникает ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: \*\*\* is not a function](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479423/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-is-not-a-function)

Comment: `var video = $(".js-video")[0];`

Comment: Помогло следующее - var video = $(".js-video").get(0);