# как считать значение из атрибута

Tags: javascript

в html вывожу циклом одинаковые блоки с атрибутом value:

```
{% for order in orders %}
    <circle value="{{order.status.percent}}" id="{{order.id}}" class="progress-ring__circle" cx="110" cy="110" r="60"></circle>
{% endfor %}
```

имеется js код, в котором нужно считать в цикле значения value:

```
<script>
    let circle = document.querySelectorAll('.progress-ring__circle');
    const radius = 60;
    const circumference = 2 * 3.14 * radius;
    for(i in circle){
        console.log(circle[i].getAttribute('value'));
    }
    const offset = circumference - percent / 100 * circumference;
    circle[i].style.strokeDashoffset = offset;
</script>
```

получает из первого тэга значение, а далее выдает ошибку: TypeError: circle[i].getAttribute is not a function

Comment: Измени цикл `for(let i = 0; i < circle.length; i++) { console.log(circle[i].getAttribute('value')); }`

Comment: Либо можно сделать такой цикл `for(let circle_item of circle) { console.log(circle_item.getAttribute('value')); }`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему возникает ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: \*\*\* is not a function](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479423/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-is-not-a-function)