# Как создать на js контейнер, в котором будут сохраняться какие-то данные, например имена?

Tags: javascript

localStorage и куки мне не подходят, потому что они запоминают и позволяют работать с введенными данными с предыдущих сеансов, а у меня нет в этом нужды, мне необходимо просто в каком-то контейнере сохранять введенные в нынешнем сеансе данные (имена)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Version1</title>

    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="messages_container" style="border: 2px solid"></div>
    
    <h1>Введите Ваше имя:</h1>
    <div id="YrName">
        <input type="text" name="name_input">
    </div>
    <div id="SendNameButton"><input type="button" name="send_name_button" value="Enter"></div>

    <div id="inhere">
        <input type="text" name="message_input">       
    </div>

    <div id="SendButton"><input type="button" name="send_message_button" value="Send message"></div>    

    <script type="application/javascript" src = "websocket_client.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

    const messagesContainer = document.querySelector("#messages_container");
    const messageInput = document.querySelector('[name=message_input]');
    const sendMessageButton = document.querySelector('[name=send_message_button]');
    const name_input = document.querySelector('[name=name_input]');
    const SendNameButton = document.querySelector('[name=send_name_button]');    

    let websocketClient = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:12345");

    websocketClient.onopen = () => {
        console.log("Client conntected!");
        websocketClient.send("Hello!");
    
        sendMessageButton.onclick = () => {
            websocketClient.send(messageInput.value);
            messageInput.value = "";
        };    

        /*SendNameButton.onclick = () => {
            websocketClient.send(name_input.value);   
            name_input.value = "";
        }; Это отправка из поля ввода имени в тот самый контейнер сбора и сохранения*/

    };

    websocketClient.onmessage = (message) => {
        const newMessage = document.createElement('div');
        newMessage.innerHTML = message.data;
        messagesContainer.appendChild(newMessage);
        console.log(message.data);
    }

    document.onkeydown = (e) => {
        if(e.key === 'Enter') {
            websocketClient.send(messageInput.value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: А обычные переменные чем вам не нравятся для этого? Можно в массив писать, если данных как бы несколько. Можно под эти цели объект создать. Ну или использовать sessionStorage, он такой же как localStorage, но забывает данные при закрытии браузера(правда остаются при обновлении страницы)

Comment: Для "текущего сеанса" может подойти `sessionStorage`...

Answer (score 0):

Я вот накидал, но, ожидаемо выдает ошибку "Uncaught TypeError TypeError: getName.send is not a function". Как мне написать функцию, которая бы решила эту ошибку?

```
const getName = localStorage.getItem('name_input', JSON.stringify(name_input));
console.log(getName);

SendNameButton.onclick = () => {
    getName.send(name_input.value);
    name_input.value = "";
};
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: [Почему возникает ошибка Uncaught TypeError TypeError: getName.send is not a function](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479423/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-is-not-a-function). Из хранилища вы не сможете подтянуть функцию, т.к. там лежит строка.

Comment: @SwaD, в хранилище лежит строка? Тогда каким образом я могу оттуда ее достать?

Comment: Никак не достанете. Разве что превратите функцию в строку, далее с помощью eval ее запустите, однако я этого не советую. Передача данных и передача функций - это разное. Не очень понятно, зачем вам передавать функцию через хранилище