# При выполнении в терминале npm run dev выдает ошибку str.toLowerCase is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
   var inflector = {
  /**
   * A helper method that applies rules based replacement to a String.
   * @private
   * @function
   * @param {String} str String to modify and return based on the passed rules.
   * @param {Array: [RegExp, String]} rules Regexp to match paired with String to use for replacement
   * @param {Array: [String]} skip Strings to skip if they match
   * @param {String} override String to return as though this method succeeded (used to conform to APIs)
   * @returns {String} Return passed String modified by passed rules.
   * @example
   *
   *     this._apply_rules( 'cows', singular_rules ); // === 'cow'
   */
    _apply_rules : function ( str, rules, skip, override ){
      if( override ){
        str = override;
      }else{
        var ignore = ( inflector.indexOf( skip, str.toLowerCase()) > -1 );

        if( !ignore ){
          var i = 0;
          var j = rules.length;

          for( ; i < j; i++ ){
            if( str.match( rules[ i ][ 0 ])){
              if( rules[ i ][ 1 ] !== undefined ){
                str = str.replace( rules[ i ][ 0 ], rules[ i ][ 1 ]);
              }
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      }

      return str;
    }
```

Форумчане, прошу помощи.
Данный файл я не создавал (как и саму функцию), он установился с Sequelize.
Знаю, что в терминале может ругаться, если toLowerCase принимает что-то кроме строки, НО 1100 строк кода и все вызовы просматривать больно, где оно принимает НЕ строку - ума не приложу.
Если надо, скину ссылкой весь файл в телеграмм или еще куда.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему возникает ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: \*\*\* is not a function](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479423/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-is-not-a-function)

Comment: Когда ругается, указывается номер строки, где произошла ошибка. Вот там и смотрите, что приходит.

Comment: Код нужно показывать текстом, не картинкой. Ошибка скорее всего связана с тем, что `str` не является строкой. Т.к. метод `toLowerCase()` метод "сточный".

Comment: @ksa отредачил код, посмотрите пожалуйста. Вроде написано, что str - строка ({String} str). Могу ошибаться, просто интересно, может поставилось криво.

Comment: Добавь вывод `console.log(typeof str)` перед строкой с ошибкой. ;)

Comment: @ksa терминал написал, что объект. Спасибо огромное, товарищи, выручили.

Comment: Может не по теме, но зачем в `indexOf` передавать строку вторым параметром? не перепутали случайно skip и строку поиска местами?
Да и вообще код немного непонятный =)