# Как заполнить масив постов данными из json объекта?

Tags: javascript, html, json

Есть несколько постов такого формата

```html
<article class="row loop-post">
  <img src="assets/images/b1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
  <h2 class="ptitle" id="ptitle">Lorem Ipsum dolor is going to be hear</h2>
  <ul class="post-meta list-unstyled nav-pills">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar">july 25, 2008</i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user">by admin</i></a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="entry-content row" id="entry-content">
    <p>Aliquam vitae sem id sem efficitur interdum phasellus ut nulla nisi sed varius lacus pharet quam rutrum enim quis rhoncu estibulum sed maximus elits quisque act semper sem tempus nisic laoreet donec ex pharetra aliquam vitae sem id sem efficitur pharetra lacus quis eleifend. <br><a href="blog-post.html" class="read-more btn btn-primary">read more</a></p>
  </div>
</article>
```

я делаю запрос и получаю данные в json, после вставляю их в каждый пост

```
    const requestURL = 'https://newsdata.io/api/1/news?apikey=pub_259912209410b5f3d450560875b2b50776dc7&q=crypto&language=en&from_date=2023-01-19&to_date=2023-01-25';
    const request = new Request(requestURL);

    const response = await fetch(request);
    const cryptoNew = await response.json();

    populateNew(cryptoNew);
}

function populateNew(obj) {
const articleList = document.getElementsByClassName('loop-post');
const articles = obj.results;
for (const article of articleList) {
    console.log(article)
    const ptitle = article.querySelector('ptitle')
    const data = article.querySelector('fa-calendar')
    const user = article.querySelector('fa-user')
    const desc = article.querySelector('#p');
    const content = article.querySelector('#h4');
    for (const arr of articles) {

        if (arr.title !== null) {
            ptitle.textContent = arr.title;
        }
        if (arr.data !== null) {
            data.textContent = arr.data;
        }
        if (arr.creator !== null) {
            user.textContent = `Creator: ${arr.creator}`;
        }
        if (arr.description !== null) {
            desc.textContent = arr.description;
        }
        if (arr.content !== null) {
            content.textContent = arr.content;
        }
        console.log(arr)
    }

    article.querySelector('img-responsive').insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', ptitle)
}
```

}

```
populate();
```

но он не вставляет в сам html, пробовал через append но выдавал ошибку

> main.get.js:24 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: article.getElementById is not a function
> at populateNew (file:///C:/Users/%D0%9F%D0%9A/Desktop/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0%20(2)/assets/js/main.get.js:24:24)
> at populate (file:///C:/Users/%D0%9F%D0%9A/Desktop/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0%20(2)/assets/js/main.get.js:13:2)

при открытии поста он открывается в другой странице развернутым

```html
<article class="row loop-post single-post">
  <img src="assets/images/b4.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
  <h2 class="ptitle">Welcome to HostPro Wordpress Theme</h2>
  <ul class="post-meta list-unstyled nav-pills">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar">july 25, 2008</i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user">by admin</i></a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="entry-content row" id="entry-content">
     <p id="p">Aliquam vitae sem id sem efficitur interdum phasellus ut nulla nisi sed varius lacus pharet quam rutrum enim quis rhoncu estibulum sed maximus elits quisque act semper sem tempus nisic laoreet donec ex pharetra aliquam vitae sem id sem efficitur pharetra lacus quis eleifend.</p>
     <br>
     <br>
     <h4 id="h4">Maecenas malesuada orci a tristique pharetra things will be much better with donec elit turpis donec orcing going to open very soon</h4>
     <br>
     <br>
     <blockquote>
       <q>Integer lacinia malesuada justo sit amet vestibulum or ms dolor nonc nullam dapibus rhoncus tristique noc ultricies enim accums dolor nullam dapibus rhoncus turpis vehicela praesent feugiat tempor hendrerit donec turpis leo eget.</q>
     </blockquote>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Возможно поможет в разгадывании ошибки [Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: article.getElementById](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479423/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

У элементов нет метода `getElementById`. Воспользуйтесь `querySelector`, он находит элементы по **CSS** селектору:

```js
// Формат таков:
// const someElement = article.querySelector(`#elementId`);
const desc = article.querySelector('#p');
const content = article.querySelector('#h4');
```

Comment: да но щас если пытаюсь внести данные в html с помощью addend, то говорит что нельзя присвоить значение null, хотя в консоль выводит все правильно

Comment: я так понимаю у вас скрипт валиться на моменте `desc.textContent = arr.description;`/`content.textContent = arr.content;`?

Comment: я сделал как ты посоветовал, теперь у меня нет ошибок но и нет результата, он по прежнему не заменяет мне тект на тект из json

Comment: если вы оставили проверки на `null` - уберите их. Или хотя-бы замените, т.к. они делаются так: `someVar !== null`, а не `someVar ==! null`. А вообще, неплохо было бы иметь на руках полный код, чтобы я точно мог сказать, что не так. Его можно обновить прямо в вопросе.

Comment: поменял код, выдает ошибку нельзя присвоить свойство null, при этом промежуточный результат выдает правильно

Comment: у вас уже есть теги с `id="p"` и `id="h4"`? Если их не будет - то код конечно же будет валиться.

Comment: да они есть, но только на странице с развернутым постом, но на ней та же ошибка, дело не в этом значит

Comment: я уже понял в чём дело: вы как-то странно пытаетесь найти элементы по классу с помощью `querySelector`: вы просто вбиваете имя класса. Однако правильным вариантом для нахождения элемента по классу будет `someElement.querySelector(".someclass")`

Comment: все разобрался, спасибо за помощь, надо было убрать строгое неравенство, короче один =

Comment: если нужно было убрать строгое неравенство, то очень вероятно, что поля могли быть и `undefined` ( точнее их могло и не быть, из-за чего возвращалось `undefined` )... Я проверил, и таки нашёл случай, когда проверки выполнялись, но поля просто не было..