# Не могу добавить кнопку EDIT в форму

Tags: javascript, reactjs, usestate

Всем добрый день. Приложение на React.
Пытаюсь добавить кнопку на элемент.

Прописал запрос на фронте в элементе PostItem.jsx в updateHandler,
прокинул в том же эл-те в  код кнопки onClick={() => updateHandler(post.id)} -  ошибок нет кроме, как на e.preventdefault (PostItem.jsx:13 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function),но  если в button прописать тип, как href={`/post/${post.id}`}, то ошибка: GET http://localhost:3000/post/51 404.
так же прописал роуты пост и апипост для изменения БД.

Подскажите свежим взглядом, что делаю (или не делаю) не так ? код прилагаю
PostItem.jsx:

```
    import React,{ useState } from 'react';
    import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
    import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
    import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
    import locale from 'date-fns/locale/ru';
    import formatDistanceToNow from 'date-fns/formatDistanceToNow';
    
    export default function PostItem({ post, handleError, deletePostHandler, user }) {
      const createDate = formatDistanceToNow(new Date(post.createdAt), { addSuffix: true, locale });
      const updateHandler = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const [err, setErr] = useState(null);
        const data = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(e.target));
    // изменение поста 
        const response = await fetch(`/api/post/${post.authorId}`, {
            method: 'PATCH',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        });
        console.log('это дата на фронте===>>', data) 
    
        if (!response.ok) {
          const error = await response.json();
          setErr(error.message);
          return;
        }
        window.location.href='/'
    
      };
    
    
      
      return (
        <Col xs={12} md={6} lg={4} className="mb-4">
          <Card>
            <Card.Img
              style={{ height: '300px', objectFit: 'cover' }}
              variant="top"
              src={`/img/${post.img}`}
              onError={handleError}
            />
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Text>{post.description}</Card.Text>
            </Card.Body>
            <Card.Footer>
              <small className="text-muted">{post?.author?.name}</small>
            </Card.Footer>
          </Card>
          <Col className="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-end">
            <div className=" col d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"> 
    
    
            <Button
              variant="success"
                disabled={user?.id !== post.authorId}
                // onClick={() => updateHandler(post.id)}
              href={`/post/${post.id}`}
              className="mt-2"
            >
              Edit
              </Button>
              
    
            <Button
              variant="danger"
              disabled={user?.id !== post.authorId}
              onClick={() => deletePostHandler(post.id)}
              className="mt-2"
            >
              Delete
            </Button>
    
    
            <span style={{ color: 'gray' }} className="ml-2">
              {createDate}
            </span>
    
          </div>
    
          </Col>
        </Col>
      );
    }
```

postRouter.js

```
    postRouter.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {
        const { authorId } = req.body;
        const post = await Post.findOne({ where: { authorId }  });
        res.render('Layout', { post });
      
      });
```

apiPostRouter.js

```
    import express from 'express';
    import fs from 'fs/promises';
    import sharp from 'sharp';
    import { Post } from '../../../db/models';
    import authCheck from '../../middlewares/authCheck';
    import checkAuthor from '../../middlewares/checkAuthor';
    import upload from '../../middlewares/multerMid';
    
    const apiPostRouter = express.Router();
    apiPostRouter.post('/', authCheck(true), upload.single('file'), async (req, res) => {
      console.log(req.body);
      try {
     
        if (!req.file) {
          return res.status(400).json({ message: 'File not found' });
        }  
        const name = `${Date.now()}.webp`;
        const outputBuffer = await sharp(req.file.buffer).webp().toBuffer();
        await fs.writeFile(`./public/img/${name}`, outputBuffer);    
        const post = await Post.create({
          description: req.body.description,
          img: name,
          authorId: req.session.user.id,
        });
        const postWithAuthor = await Post.findOne({ where: { id: post.id }, include: 'author' });
        res.json(postWithAuthor);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Server error' });
      }
    });
    
       apiPostRouter.patch('/:id', async (req, res) => {
        await Post.update(req.body, { where: { id: req.params.id } });
        const updatedPost = await Post.findByPk(req.params.id);
        res.json(updatedPost);
      });
    
    apiPostRouter.delete('/:id', checkAuthor, async (req, res) => {
      try {
        const post = await Post.findByPk(req.params.id);
        fs.unlink(`./public/img/${post.img}`).catch((e) => console.log(e));
        if (!post) {
          res.status(404).json({ message: 'Post not found' });
        }
        await post.destroy();
        res.json({ message: 'Post deleted' });
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Server error' });
      }
    });
    export default apiPostRouter;
```

PostUpDate.jsx

```
    import React from 'react';
    export default function PostUpDatePage({ post, updateHandler}) {
    
      return (
        
        <div className="row mt-3">
          <div className="col">
            <form onSubmit={updateHandler}>
              <div className="mb-3">
                <label htmlFor="exampleFormControlInput1" className="form-label">Title</label>
                <input
                  name="description"
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="exampleFormControlInput1"
                  placeholder="type text.."
                  defaultValue={post.description}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="mb-3">
              <label htmlFor="exampleFormControlInput1" className="form-label">Edit your post..</label>
                <input
                  name="file"
                  type="file"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="exampleFormControlInput1"          
                  placeholder="Add new file.."
                    defaultValue={post.file}
                  />
            </div>
                  <button type="submit" className="btn btn-warning">Save</button>
              </form>          
          </div>
    
      );
    }
```

Comment: У вас тут ряд ошибок. Что бы передать событие нажатия кнопки и отменить дефолтное поведение(что бы e.preventDefault(); отработал), событие клика должно быть записано так: `onClick={(event) => updateHandler(event)}`. Далее, вот это `new FormData(e.target)` работать не будет, т.к. **e** это событие, а **e.targert** это собственно кнопка. Функция будет отрабатывать только по событию отправки формы, однако в ваших роутах я не вижу пути **/api/post/**

Comment: Самый первый кусок кода :  const response = await fetch(`/api/post/${post.authorId}` в моем посте. Или  я что-то не понимаю о чем речь ? сорри за глупые вопросы, но я только учусь.

Comment: "Далее, вот это new FormData(e.target) работать не будет," - как нужно написать, что бы работало ?

Comment: По поводу **/api/post/** -  вы сюда шлете запрос, однако на ноде нет обработчика данного адреса. Про FormDate - не понятно, как надо в вашем случае, т.к. данный компонент не вызывается из компонента **PostItem** и как он связан, не понятно. Однако, в реакте все должно идти от состояния компонента и обращений к реальным DOM узлам быть не должно(на сколько это возможно). И в целом, я бы вам советовал отказаться от тега form, вы ведь используете fetch запросы

Comment: Ну и если вы только учитесь, то делите задачки на более мелкие. Сначала бэк сделайте, что бы он умел простые запросы принимать, отладьте, потом на фронте усложняйте запросы и смотрите как бэк реагирует на это, потом уже к формам с большим объемом данных переходите.

Comment: Пока не очень понимаю. почему нет  /api/post/ -обработчика данного адреса, если он есть в файле apiPostRouter и выглядит следующим образом:     ```apiPostRouter.patch('/post/:id', checkAuthor, async (req, res) =>{
    const {id} = req.params
  await Post.update(req.body, { where: { id } });
    const updatedPost = await Post.findByPk(id);
    res.json(updatedPost);
  });
``` Или вы что-то другое имеете ввиду ?

Comment: Обратитесь напрямую к вашим роутам, обложитесь консоль логами, и посмотрите, какой роут будет вызываться при том или ином запросе. 404 ошибка не просто так возникает... По поводу ошибки [e.preventDefault is not a function](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479423/). Т.е. вам нужно слона есть по частям и декомпозировать ваши задачи и проблемы, как описано комментарием выше. Судя по набору ошибок, такое ощущение, что этот код написан сходу, без тестирования и возможно даже не вами.... Если писать код последовательно, то обычно возникает 1-2 ошибки, а тут (бэк, фронт) целый набор...

Comment: Спасибо! дельный комментарий. займусь проверкой!