# Как удалить подзадачу todolist в redux-toolkit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

Всем добрый день. Делаю расширенный список задач (todolist) на redux-toolkit. Не пойму - каким образом удалять определённые подзадачи? Сейчас функция removeSubTodo() выдаёт ошибку - "state.findindex is not a function." Всё работает, кроме этого. Ниже привожу максимально обрезанную версию кода. Слайс:

```js
const todosSlice = createSlice({
    name: '@@todos',
    initialState: [],
    reducers: {
        addTodo: {
            reducer: (state: any, action: any) => {
                state.push(action.payload)
            },
            prepare: (todoName: string) => ({
                payload: {
                    id: 1,
                    todoName,
                },
            }),
        },
        addSubTodo: (
            state: any,
            action: any
        ) => {
            return state.map((param: any) =>
                param.id === action.payload.id
                    ? {
                          ...param,
                          extraParams: {
                              ...param.extraParams,
                              enumType: {
                                  ...param.extraParams.enumType,
                                  variants: [
                                      ...param.extraParams.enumType.variants,
                                      {
                                          id: action.payload.extraParams
                                              ?.enumType?.variants![0].id,
                                          varMeaning:
                                              action.payload.extraParams
                                                  ?.enumType?.variants![0]
                                                  .varMeaning,
                                          varNickName:
                                              action.payload.extraParams
                                                  ?.enumType?.variants![0]
                                                  .varNickName,
                                      },
                                  ],
                              },
                          },
                      }
                    : param
            )
        },
        removeSubTodo: (state: any, action: any) => {
            const variantToRemoveIndex = state.findindex(
                (id: any) => id === action.payload.id
            )
            if (variantToRemoveIndex === -1) {
                return state
            }
            const param = state[variantToRemoveIndex]
            const updatedVariants = {
                ...param,
                variants: param.extraParams.enumType.variants.filter(
                    (variant: any) => variant.id !== action.payload.id
                ),
            }
            return {
                ...state,
                state: [
                    ...state.slice(0, variantToRemoveIndex),
                    updatedVariants,
                    ...state.slice(variantToRemoveIndex + 1),
                ],
            }
        },
    },
})
```

Код разметки:

```js
const dispatch = useDispatch()
const paramList = useSelector((state: { params: [] }) => state.params)

...

return (
        <>
    {paramItem.extraParams?.enumType?.variants?.map(
                                            (item) => (
                                                <div
                                                    className="flex flex-row justify-between box-border"
                                                    key={item.id}
                                                >
                                                    <div className="flex flex-col justify-between w-1/2 mr-2">
                                                        {item.varMeaning}
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div className="flex flex-col justify-between w-1/2">
                                                        {item.varNickName}
                                                    </div>
                                                    <Button
                                                        onClick={() => {
                                                            dispatch(
                                                                removeSubTodo(
                                                                    paramItem.id
                                                                )
                                                            )
                                                        }}
                                                    >
                                                        X
                                                    </Button>
                                                </div>
                                            )
                                        )}
<>
)
...
```

Comment: [state.findindex is not a function](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479423) - общее описание, как искать и бороться. Возможно, причина в том, что у массивов(если state это массив), нет метода findindex, однако есть метод findIndex(Index с большой буквы)