# React хук - setState is not a function при использовании пользовательского хука

Tags: reactjs, функции, react-hook

Пример с проблемой реализован тут: https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-fast-8dfqj5?file=/src/App.js

Коротко, суть:

1. Есть Хук `useHook`, в который передаются функции **setState1** и **setState2**
2. Хук в свою очередь возвращает кнопку `Button`
3. У кнопки в событии `onClick` вызывается setState1 куда передаётся объект, где одним из полей является someFunction, внутри внутри этой функции вызывается setState2
4. При использовании кнопки, в неё нужно передать свойство buttonName

В моём варианте реализации, при нажатии на кнопку появляется ошибка:

```
TypeError setState1 is not a function
   7 | return (
   8 |   <button
   9 |     onClick={() => {
> 10 |       setState1({
     |      ^
  11 |         data: "data from button",
  12 |         callback: someFunction
  13 |       });
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить код и допустимый ли это архитектурный подход? Можно ли подобный функционал реализовать иначе? Может тут хук и не нужен

App.jsx

```
import { useState } from "react";
import useHook from "./useHook";

export default function App() {
  const [state1, setState1] = useState({});
  const [state2, setState2] = useState("");

  const [Button] = useHook(setState1, setState2);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("state1", state1);
    console.log("state2", state2);
  }, [state1, state2]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Button buttonName={"name of button"} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

useHook.jsx

```
export default function useHook({ setState1, setState2 }) {
  const someFunction = () => {
    setState2("state is setted");
  };

  const Button = ({ buttonName }) => {
    return (
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setState1({
            data: "data from button",
            callback: someFunction
          });
        }}
      >
        {buttonName}
      </button>
    );
  };

  return [Button];
}
```

Comment: по-моему, ваш хук useHook скорее компонент, чем хук. Хуки содержат в себе логику и возвращают состояние и методы, а никак не то, что должно рендериться.

Comment: [Почему возникает ошибка TypeError setState1 is not a function](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479423/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш хук, больше похож на компонент, чем на классический хук. Обычно хук возвращает состояние и функцию для изменения внутреннего состояния.

> Если вы хотите оставить как есть, то

Для того, что бы исправить ошибку, необходимо поправить аргументы вашего хука, либо изменить их передачу в сам хук.

##### Вариант 1(Меняем список аргументов в хуке):

Меняем это

```
export default function useHook({ setState1, setState2 })
```

На это

```
export default function useHook(setState1, setState2)
```

##### Вариант 2(Меняем передачу аргументов в хук):

Меняем с

```
const [Button] = useHook(setState1, setState2);
```

На

```
const [Button] = useHook({ setState1, setState2 });
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!