# Здравствуйте, хочу применить подсвечивание карточек для всех карточек, однако консоль выдает ошибку block.addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript

Помогите пожалуйста

Вот сам код js

```
const root = document.getElementsByClassName('.catalog__card');

const block = document.getElementsByClassName('.card-wrap');

  block.addEventListener('mousemove', evt => {

      x = evt.offsetX / block.clientWidth;

      y = evt.offsetY / block.clientHeight;

      block.style.setProperty('--mouseX', x);


      block.style.setProperty('--mouseY', y);

      block.classList.add('background');

})
addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
 block.classList.remove('background');
})
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему возникает ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: \*\*\* is not a function](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479423/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-is-not-a-function)

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` - возвращает коллекцию, а не адоин элемент

Comment: И ещё... Если символ `.` (_точка_) не входит в название класса, то передавать методу [getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) её не нужно. Т.е. пишите просто `document.getElementsByClassName('catalog__card');` и `document.getElementsByClassName('card-wrap');`