# Проблемы с ReactQuery v4 "из коробки"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, запрос, fetch

И снова я тут, товарищи. Сел за изучение React Query и благополучно столкнулся с очень неприятной ошибкой прямо, если так можно выразиться, "из коробки".

Уточню, писать, что надо просто прочитать ошибку, не нужно, я уже ее и читал, и гуглил, и куда только не пихал)

[image: Ошибка:]

Код main.tsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.tsx'
import './index.css'
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-query'

const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false
    }
  }
});

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <App />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```

Код в App.tsx:

```
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";

const todoId = 1;

function App() {

  const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery(
    ['todos', todoId],
    () => fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').then(response=>response.json())
  )

  return (
    <div>
      {
      data ?( 
        <h1>Todo: {data}</h1>
      ):(
        <h1>No todos</h1>
      )
      }
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: [Ошибка :)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479423/). Судя по всему, один из переданных(или не переданных) параметров, должна быть функция, но она таковой не является

Comment: Боюсь огорчить, но нет, второй параметр функция. Решил протестировать и приложение вообще перестало грузиться. И даже в документации говорится о том, что второй параметр это функция.

Comment: О! Если верить доке, то оберните ваши параметры так: `useQuery( { queryKey: [], queryFn: () => ... } )`

Comment: Это первое, что я полез пробовать(