# Почему при проверке роли в discord появляется ошибка "message.member.roles.some is not a function"?

Tags: javascript, бот, discord

У меня есть несколько ролей "младший мод", "старший мод". Хотел бы добавить проверку в названии роли.

```
client.client.on("messageCreate", message => {
    if(message.content == '*hi') {
        message.channel.send("Hello!");

        if(message.member.roles.some(role => role.name.includes('Mod'))) {
            console.log('suo')
        }
}
```

Но у меня появляется следующая ошибка:

> TypeError: message.member.roles.some is not a function

Comment: [TypeError: message.member.roles.some is not a function](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479423/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-is-not-a-function) Подозреваю, что **message.member.roles** не массив

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cвойство `message.member.roles` представляет собой коллекцию ролей, а метод `.some()` применяется к массивам, а не к коллекциям `Discord.js`.

Вот **исправленная проверка**:

```
member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Mod')
```

Comment: Но тогда оно строго определяет ведь оператор === точно равно как и == тогда как сделать чтобы искало по совподелнию типо MN Moderator

Comment: @Mapahce2212 Для поиска ролей по частичному совпадению имени, используйте метод `includes()`

Comment: `member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name.includes('Mod'));`

Comment: Если ответ Вам помог и больше вопросов нет, нажмите галочку рядом с ответом :)