# передать input данные в динамическом элементе в react

Tags: reactjs, react-hook

У меня есть код, в котором я могу динамически создавать компонент с изображениями и сохранять его состояние.

Состояние сохраняется в этом массиве:

```
const [UploadLogos, setUploadLogos] = useState([0]);
const dynamicLogos = (id, url) => {
    setUploadLogos((el) => {
      let ArrayLogos = [...el]; 
      ArrayLogos[id] = url; 
      return ArrayLogos 
    })
};
```

Код работает, как надо, но также, внутри компонента `SimpleComponent` есть input, в котором я хочу указать данные и сохранить это состояние:

```
<input type="number" value={{}} onChange={() => {}} />
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как это сделать? Спасибо!

Вот весь код:

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { SimpleComponent } from './SimpleComponent ';

function App() {

  const [UploadLogos, setUploadLogos] = useState([0]);
  const dynamicLogos = (id, url) => {
        setUploadLogos((el) => {
          let ArrayLogos = [...el]; 
          ArrayLogos[id] = url; 
          return ArrayLogos 
        })
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          setUploadLogos([...UploadLogos, UploadLogos.length])
        }
      >
        Add
      </button>
      {UploadLogos.map((logo, i) => (
        <SimpleComponent
          key={i}
          id={i}
          Image={logo}
          setImage={dynamicLogos}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**SimpleComponent.jsx**

```
export function SimpleComponent({id, Image, setImage}) {
    return (
      <>
        <input 
            type="file" accept="image/*"
            onChange={event => { if (!event.target.files[0]) return; setImage(id, URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0])) }} 
        />
        <img src={Image} /> 
        <input type="number" value={{}} onChange={() => {}} />
      </>   
    )
}
```

Comment: Такое ощущение, что этот код не ваш, раз такие вопросы. Однако... у вас сейчас есть массив цифр(потом вы вместо цифр, записываете изображение), сделайте вместо него массив обьектов вида `{ img: null, input: '' }` и записывайте в img картинку, а в input ваш инпут, ну и чуток рендер надо переделать будет с `Image={logo}` на `Image={logo.img}`

Comment: Не полностью, но в целом код мой :) спасибо за идею

Comment: @SwaD, получаю ошибку `UploadLogos.map is not function`

Comment: [UploadLogos.map is not function](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479423/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-is-not-a-function) - Как диагностировать и исправлять

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переделывать сильно не стал, поэтому стиль кода ваш.

И так. Нам понадобится превратить состояние из массива примитивов в массив объектов. Допустим

```
const [UploadLogos, setUploadLogos] = useState([{ url: '', inp: 0 }]);
```

Меняем функцию изменения состояния, добавляем данные инпута

```
const dynamicLogos = (id, url, inp) => {
    setUploadLogos((el) => {
      let ArrayLogos = [...el]; 
      if (url !== null) ArrayLogos[id] = { ...ArrayLogos[id], url: url };
      if (inp !== null) ArrayLogos[id] = { ...ArrayLogos[id], inp: inp };
      return ArrayLogos; 
    })
};
```

Меняем рендер, передаем изображение и сам инпут(теперь logo это объект с ключами url и inp

```
{UploadLogos.map((logo, i) => (
    <SimpleComponent
      key={i}
      id={i}
      Image={logo.url}
      inp={logo.inp}
      setImage={dynamicLogos}
    />
))}
```

Меняем компонент SimpleComponent

```
export function SimpleComponent({id, Image, setImage, inp}) {
    return (
      <>
        <input 
            type="file" accept="image/*"
            onChange={event => { if (!event.target.files[0]) return; setImage(id, URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]), null) }} 
        />
        <img src={Image} /> 
        <input type="number" value={inp} onChange={(e) => setImage(id, null, +e.target.value)} />
        <br />
      </>   
    )
}
```

Полный код:

```js
export function SimpleComponent({id, Image, setImage, inp}) {
    return (
      <>
        <input 
            type="file" accept="image/*"
            onChange={event => { if (!event.target.files[0]) return; setImage(id, URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]), null) }} 
        />
        <img src={Image} /> 
        <input type="number" value={inp} onChange={(e) => setImage(id, null, +e.target.value)} />
        <br />
      </>   
    )
}

function App() {

  const [UploadLogos, setUploadLogos] = useState([{ img: '', inp: 0 }]);
  const dynamicLogos = (id, url, inp) => {
        setUploadLogos((el) => {
          let ArrayLogos = [...el]; 
          if (url !== null) ArrayLogos[id] = { ...ArrayLogos[id], url: url };
          if (inp !== null) ArrayLogos[id] = { ...ArrayLogos[id], inp: inp };
          return ArrayLogos; 
        })
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          setUploadLogos([...UploadLogos, { url: '', inp: 0 }])
        }
      >
        Add
      </button>
      <br />
      {UploadLogos.map((logo, i) => (
        <SimpleComponent
          key={i}
          id={i}
          Image={logo.url}
          inp={logo.inp}
          setImage={dynamicLogos}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Рабочий код в песочнице](https://reactplayground.vercel.app/#N4IgLgziBcBmCGAbCBTANCAbrK1QEsA7AExQA8A6AK1xHwFsAHAewCcwACAQUcY9lbN6HAOQUA9D0bUIZEQB1CDFuw4AlFPADGnAUNGtNOhUqZtOwDlsPwwKNc2acAvv0HCRNnQFpiQ8VqI+CiEYCaKWsyEEJyRofBEKKwcALwcfloArvQhYBQA5ihgAKKIKDmhAEIAngCSxAAUno5hAJQRUTEcgk6pVjZ2Dk4NcWAJhEnthD15hiRJDYoc6kZ51pp2peW5i4TLyxraeQDKYKz4OgCyzKRoS-uEmYiId3v7hzoU67YoWxVgDSkU2WU1aIAwUhkZBgdDMqg+YDQHEsmVQpx+HFceg8XjCimU5g4MWqZWIbn0ImJpO8kTME1CEHCEzIKl0mUIOnwUQ4x2UZQAwkIWPSAcB8MQkbV6PBCkjUGApTL0BwiIxnK1kfdloYwJlWHtdvt9gAeAB8WqNHGNqsynAtlv2YGqjBQKXkIFg+DK7o42i0KEYYDdsKV4gAVO77Q6OFF+QALeCEQopYAoTC5VKm5Eq2AcBoAQjTuQoY1YhTynrKEAA2gAGAC6Gp1esIAG4iUVFYUGuKkQBVNQAGS+AxQAHkAEZUFA6AeDhpF0Il+BlooUSsoGsN1pIx7PDXOVxR5bic1vB3W+j5ImsLQprsoVynjjHq02zhOl3Bx70CdJH2YEgmSumKhBqjGhDxomybAAuGopFm8oPj2EocHuLwcAA1Cgy6rnkgGIMBrRPme0ZWhOySnlGxrPssFpTM4iiKLA7KctyUgNBqwBMW8cRdNWfaMIgzDwMQg7MPkzAQHKRSCcJoniZJED1n0qIoOidgNNWlgMPk0CiCISKqvptaYo2rb3HxnDENUhDwPQFyKVJfQoUieoYaq8FZtx56WvKckiWJElSQ0C6IF5mq+Q6ZScFwrCsPA1RORAfTVhQ6UoIg9btq+yz4LmDTuRw+YpGk6EanFCVJcFNbiipaSWOlFCVYlyXVnVbmsIg+lFc4FlRZa+V5qqxWlWhTzhdw8WtTV7XEPV2ZNS11VKXN9ZGWB+kjX1uXdEULZTVVyU5QNyzqvcO1vPczb6nmFrGsQ+CYFYiDwBAEAAHL2a67pSO6pGWsaE62mAUSvrGQRaAA1imnGZrt-lCYFyVaU1AUKTVSIol1+kiIZKqbRwpnOI2r6MQNAMOlwxDENR4jA2AoOEJTJoURwVEDcA6NBUpFDSowoXCZJRkRYa0bGryTACkKUS5LtUMoNUKb4OTZF5cQyuq2rD4pkLzAUO5WtkaquvBRQqpG9GSHSjBNl2Q5WjJZbRocw6rTEfd4iPZgAOtP15OKOQrLpCgCBPLFvAgIeQA)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Все полностью повторил, но получаю ошибку - `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {url, inp}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
` Буду разбираться! Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: @rabbit Значит не все повторили. Проверяйте по строчкам, сверяйте с полным кодом, который приложен.

Comment: Уже даже скопировал ваш код. Та же ошибка - не валидные объекты. Странно. Версия React последняя.

Comment: причем, реагирует на этот хук `const [UploadLogos, setUploadLogos] = useState([{ url: '', inp: 0 }]);`

Comment: Добавьте в ваш вопрос обновленный код, не удаляя старый, просто ниже.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Разобрался. Спасибо еще раз!