# Не работает listUsers в firebase. Как получить данные всех пользователей Authentication?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Выводит ошибку

> *config__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2*_.auth.listUsers is not a function
> TypeError: *config__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2*_.auth.listUsers is not
> a function

Компонента App.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { auth } from './config';
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

function App() {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
        const listAllUsers = (nextPageToken) => {
            auth
                .listUsers(1000, nextPageToken)
                .then((listUsersResult) => {
                    setUsers(listUsersResult.users)
                })
        }
        listAllUsers()
        console.log(users);
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="App">

        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Конфигурация

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxx",
    projectId: "xxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxx",
    appId: "xxxxx",
    measurementId: "xxxxx"
};
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app)
```

Comment: Почитайте про ошибку [is not a function](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479423/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-is-not-a-function). Вам надо посмотреть, что такое у вас переменная auth и есть ли там нужный вам метод. P.S. в useEffect переменеая users будет `[]` всегда, т.к. там будет начальное состояние. И оборачивание кода в функцию - лишнее