# Ошибка в сборке GULP

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, gulp

Не понимаю из за чего появляется ошибка

```
[15:20:26] 'watching' errored after 1.04 s
[15:20:26] TypeError: msg is not a function
```

и пути

```
node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\eazy-logger\index.js:210:59)
node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\eazy-logger\index.js:146:10)
node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\eazy-logger\index.js:109:26)
```

пробовал переустанавливать gulp локально и поставил версию browser-sync поменьше 2.28.1 - ничего не помогло

Comment: Покажите часть кода, которая вызывает данную ошибку.

Comment: [из за чего появляется ошибка TypeError: msg is not a function](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479423/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-is-not-a-function)